# How to include seperate PHP file to class in callback function

Tags: php

I am getting trouble including the seperate PHP file in callback function.

```
add_menu_page('Keyword Analyzer', 'Keyword Analyzer', 'manage_options', 
              'keyword_analyzer_menu', 'Key_Analyzer_Groups::init');
```

My Key_Analyzer_Groups class has the following codes:

```
class Key_Analyzer_Groups {



    public static function init() {

        include_once plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'admin/templates/groups.php';
    }
}
```

but if i directly include the html on the `init()` function then output works as expected but not with the included file.

I am sure there should be some trick to seperate the view templates. Please guide me to the right direction.

Folder Structure:

```
plugin
- admin
  - views
   - key-analyzer-groups.php ( Key_Analyzer_Groups CLASS )
  - templates
   - groups.php ( Holds HTML Parts )
```

Comment: is it namespaced?

Comment: @Nath no it is not.

Comment: Does `array('Key_Analyzer_Groups', 'init')` work?

Comment: @kero i used static method ```public static function init```, thats why i used ```Key_Analyzer_Groups::init``` on callback.

Comment: i tried with ```array('Key_Analyzer_Groups', 'init')``` its not working.

Comment: So `Key_Analyzer_Groups::init()` is working? But the include inside it isn't? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @JacobPeattie right.

Comment: So what's the folder structure here. Where is the file that `Key_Analyzer_Groups` is in relative to the main plugin file? And where is `admin/templates/..` relative to that?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I have updated the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with the path you're using to include the file.

`plugin_dir_path()` just gets the directory of the given file/directory with a trailing slash. So if your code is here:

```
plugin/admin/views/key-analyzer-groups.php
```

Then `dirname( __FILE__ )` will return

```
plugin/admin/views
```

So `plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) )` will return

```
plugin/admin/
```

Which means that you are trying to include this path:

```
plugin/admin/admin/templates/groups.php
```

Which doesn't exist.

If you want a reliable way to get the directory for your plugin to use throughout your code, then what you should do is define a function in your root plugin file that returns the path, then use that function throughout your code:

```
function key_analyzer_plugin_path() {
    return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
}
```

Then use that function in your other files to include:

```
class Key_Analyzer_Groups {
    public static function init() {
        include_once key_analyzer_plugin_path() . 'admin/templates/groups.php';
    }
}
```

You could also tweak this approach to create a function for including files inside your plugin:

```
function key_analyzer_include( $file ) {
    $file = ltrim( $file, '/' );

    include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . $file;
}
```

Now you can use that function to include all your files by passing it a path relative to the main plugin file:

```
class Key_Analyzer_Groups {
    public static function init() {
        key_analyzer_include( 'admin/templates/groups.php' );
    }
}
```